# how can write sql query statement with if-else

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to to select from db

```
if id=0 select * from tbl
else select * from tbl where id= :id
```

how can use it in mysql query?

Comment: from where id come, you are talking about procedure/function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from tbl where :id = 0
union all
select * from tbl where :id <> 0 and id = :id
```

This is just a single query and it will execute only one branch as the specified `:id` value. When `:id=0`, the first query's where condition become `true` and the result is the same as `select * from tbl`. When `:id<>0`, the result of the first query will be empty, however, the second query will return the result of `select * from tbl where id=:id`.

Comment: @X.L.Ant Yes, you're right. Rimas's and Mureinik's answers look more compact.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between both your queries is just the `where` clause - you can express this with the `or` logical operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tbl
WHERE  (:id = id) OR (:id = 0)
```

Of course, this could be further cleaned up with the `in` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tbl
WHERE  :id IN (id, 0)
```

Comment: Seems that in case where id = 0, OP wants to fetch the whole table.

Comment: id in my tabel is 1 2 3 and i wanna when user dosent set id show all rows with id 1 2 and 3

Comment: Then you aren't talking about `id=0`, but about `:id=0` - edited my solution accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (id=0)  then 
select * from tbl
else 
select * from tbl where id= :id
end if;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl
  WHERE id = :id OR 0 = :id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create function that takes your id as a parameter and then you can use mySql IF statement. 
Here you have simple and quick tutorial about IF statement and also example of function [IF statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html).

Be aware that mySql has build-in IF() function also.